# How to pass reference of a specific listitem onClick to to be used in another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have a list of items (users projects) , and when a project is clicked it needs to redirect to a page where the user can edit that clicked project (list item ).

Here is how I currently list the items

```
renderingElements() {

       ...
        else {


            // Array @projectInfo : Will have objects with info from each project user currently has (title,url,genre,description)
            const projectsInfo = this.state.projectsOfUser.map(project => {
                console.log('^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^', project);
                return {

                    videoID: project._id,
                    videoTitle: project.title,
                    videoURL: project.videoURL,
                    genre: project.genre,
                    description: project.description

                }

            });

             const listItems = this.state.projectsOfUser.map((project, i) =>
                <li key={i} className="project-list-container__list__list-items" onClick={this.goToDetailComponent.bind(this)} >

                    {/* Not changing mutating in state array */}
                    {/* Passes info to each component, info is from our array of of objects with video info */}
                    <Project projectObject={projectsInfo[i]} />

                </li>
            );

            return listItems;

        }

    }
```

Here Is how the list is rendered

```
return (
            <div className="project-list-container">

                <ul className="project-list-container__list">

                    {/* If user has projects, render the list of projects */}
                    {/* {this.state.projectsOfUser && listItems} */}
                    {this.renderingElements()}

                </ul>

            </div>

        );
```

My goal is to be able to click a list item, hit a route on the react-router and pass it the clicked project object information for me to use in that second component

```
oToDetailComponent = () => {

        console.log('############################', someDataToPass)

        this.props.history.push(`/projectwork`) // how do i pass data of the specific project to this url/component

    };
```

Comment: Your `this.props.history.push("/projectwork")` line means you are try to pass the data like one page to another page and hopefully they are in parallel but in react it is only support to pass data through props from parent component to child component. So you list itsm should be in show/hide style. Another way you can pass data using Redux or similar type of stuff. But without Redux if you want to pass data inter component like page redirection either you have to pass through params or query string

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the id of the project i click before trying redirect also, but yeah alot of helpful answers on how to use history once i get his part figured out

Comment: id is just an example, you can pass any thing like you are able to pass in these two format

1)  `'/item/[anything string/number]'` or 

2)  `'/item?anything=anything'`  and for your detail page you just retrieve the whole object by id or any uniqueKey that you are suppose to pass through params or querystring

Comment: sorry , to specify i meant getting the info to put into the query string in the first place is where I'm struggling

Comment: You can pass data through `this.props.history.push("/projectwork", someDataToPass)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree very much with this way to pass data to routes, the correct way to do it should be to setup a dynamic route in your router and retrive data directly from your ProjectDetail Component using the `match` param and calling data from a globalState:

```
<Route path="Project/:ProjectId" />
```

By the way, following your snippet, you can pass data in the push in this way:

```
const getProjectObject = (project) => ({
  videoID: project._id,
  videoTitle: project.title,
  videoURL: project.videoURL,
  genre: project.genre,
  description: project.description
})

const renderItemList = (project) => {
  const { projectsOfUser } = this.state;
  const { history } = this.props;

  return projectsOfUser.map((project) => {
    const projectObj = getProjectObject(project);

    const navigateToProject = () => {
      history.push({
        pathname: '/projectWork',
        state: { project: projectObj }
      });
    }

    return (
      <li key={`project-${project._id}`} onClick={navigateToProject}>
        <Project project={projectObj} />
      </li>
    ) 
  })
}
```

In your ProjectDetail component you will able to get your project:

```
//in case of class component
const { project } = this.props.location.state
//in case of functional component
const { project } = props.location.state
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but still a bit lost, I'm new to react so I understand bits and pieces here but I'm having trouble following the flow of information here, can you simplify or explain how this works a bit more?

Comment: Are you using react-router?

Comment: Yes. The renderItemList I don't understand very well, specifically {history} = this.props, but I'm assuming navigateToProject is declared in the map somehow binds it to each list item?

Comment: And I'm alittle burnt out at trying so many things for so long so excuse the dumb question, but I'm also unsure where to place renderItemList where I would be passing it a project argument, or is that left unused? I'm going to update my post with more context of how my code is

Comment: Maybe you need to learn very well javascript before to start with react.
`const { history } = this.props` is called destructuring  in js. It's the same to write `const history = this.props.history`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this. You can pass your data/object from one component to another component by this way too

```
<button
  onClick={() =>
    this.props.history.push("/item", {
      id: 1,
      name: "test",
      otherData: "other data"
    })
  }
>
  Save
</button>
```

And you can retrieve that data in your desire component from `location`

`this.props.location.state`

Here I just gave a detail example, where I just pass some data/object from home component to item component

**home.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
class Home extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>this is home page</h1>
        <Link to="/item">List of item</Link>
        <button
          onClick={() =>
            this.props.history.push("/item", {
              id: 1,
              name: "test",
              otherData: "other data"
            })
          }
        >
          Save
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

**item.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class Item extends Component {

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.location.state);
    return (
        <h1>
          item: {this.props.location.state.name}{" "}
          {this.props.location.state.otherData}
        </h1>
    );
  }
}

export default Item;
```

make sure you are properly maintain the routes as follows in App.js

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./home";
import Item from "./item";

class App extends Component {

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/item" component={Item} />
          <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import "./index.css";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score 0):

I used an arrow function on list item to get the information I needed on click , which in this case was the unique project object. Vik has an amazing answer as well

```
   const listItems = this.state.projectsOfUser.map((project, i) =>

                <li key={i}
                    className="project-list-container__list__list-items"
                    onClick={() => this.handleClick(project)}
                >

                    {/* Not changing mutating in state array */}
                    {/* Passes info to each component, info is from our array of of objects with video info */}
                    <Project projectObject={projectsInfo[i]} />

                </li>
            );
```

I did however see this is a "soft bad practice" and it's more efficient to use a sub component so after I make sure things are working I will do that.